# Haskell proof checker for FOL with equality

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, automated-theorem-proving

Ignoring issues of efficiency, is this a correct implementation in Haskell of a proof checker for first order logic with equality? I am especially concerned about the `subIn`, `admitsVar` and `admitsTerm` functions. Also, do any of the predicate rules need to check that a variable is not free in the context?

````
{-
Hilbert style first order mathematical logic with equality using named variables.

Modified from "Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning" by John Harrison.
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/atp/index.html
-}


{-
Func "c" [] : A constant named "c"
Func "f" [v] : A function named "f" of one variable v
-}
data Term = Var String
          | Func String [Term]
            deriving (Show, Eq)

{-
Pred "P" [] : A propositional variable named "P"
Pred "Eq" [s, t] : s = t
-}
data Formula = Pred String [Term]
             | Not Formula
             | Imp Formula Formula
             | Forall String Formula
               deriving (Show, Eq)

type Context = [Formula]

data Theorem = Theorem Context Formula
               deriving (Show, Eq)

{-
From "First Order Mathematical Logic" by Angelo Margaris:

An occurrence of a variable $v$ in a formula $P$ is bound if and only if
it occurs in a subformula of $P$ of the form $\forall v Q$. An occurrence
of $v$ in $P$ is free if and only if it is not a bound occurrence. The
variable $v$ is free or bound in $P$ according as it has a free or bound
occurrence in $P$.

If $P$ is a formula, $v$ is a variable, and $t$ is a term, then $P(t/v)$ is
the result of replacing each free occurrence of $v$ in $P$ by an occurrence
of $t$.

If $v$ and $u$ are variables and $P$ is a formula, then $P$ admits $u$ for $v$
if and only if there is no free occurrence of $v$ in $P$ that becomes a
bound occurrence of $u$ in $P(u/v)$. If $t$ is a term, then $P$ admits $t$ for
$v$ if and only if $P$ admits for $v$ every variable in $t$.
-}

-- occursIn v t = there exists an occurrence of v in t.
occursIn :: String -> Term -> Bool
occursIn v (Var v') = v == v'
occursIn v (Func _ terms) = any (occursIn v) terms

-- freeIn v p = there exists an occurrence of v in p that is free.
freeIn :: String -> Formula -> Bool
freeIn v (Pred _ terms) = any (occursIn v) terms
freeIn v (Not p) = freeIn v p
freeIn v (Imp p q) = freeIn v p || freeIn v q
freeIn v (Forall v' p) = v /= v' && freeIn v p

{-
subIn p t v = p(t/v) = the result of replacing each free occurrence of
v in p by an occurrence of t.
-}
subIn :: Formula -> Term -> String -> Formula
subIn (Pred name terms) t v = Pred name (map (\t' -> subInTerm t' t v) terms) where
  {-
  subInTerm t' t v = t'(t/v) = the result of replacing each occurrence of
  v in t' by an occurrence of t.
  -}
  subInTerm :: Term -> Term -> String -> Term
  subInTerm (Var v') t v = if v == v' then t else Var v'
  subInTerm (Func name terms) t v = Func name (map (\t' -> subInTerm t' t v) terms)
subIn (Not p) t v = Not (subIn p t v)
subIn (Imp p q) t v = Imp (subIn p t v) (subIn q t v)
subIn (Forall v' p) t v = if v == v' then Forall v' p else Forall v' (subIn p t v)

{-
admitsVar p u v = p admits u for v = there is no free occurrence of 
v in p that becomes a bound occurrence of u in p(u/v).
-}
admitsVar :: Formula -> String -> String -> Bool
admitsVar p u v = go p u v [] where
  go :: Formula -> String -> String -> [String] -> Bool
  go (Pred _ terms) u v binders = not (any (occursIn v) terms)
                               || elem v binders
                               || notElem u binders
  go (Not p) u v binders = go p u v binders
  go (Imp p q) u v binders = go p u v binders && go q u v binders
  go (Forall v' p) u v binders = go p u v (v' : binders)

{-
admitsTerm p t v = p admits for v every variable in t.
-}
admitsTerm :: Formula -> Term -> String -> Bool
admitsTerm p (Var u) v = admitsVar p u v
admitsTerm p (Func _ terms) v = all (\t -> admitsTerm p t v) terms


-- Assumption

assume :: Context -> Formula -> Theorem
assume gamma p = if elem p gamma then Theorem gamma p else error "assume"


-- Propositional calculus

-- |- (p -> (q -> p))
prop_1 :: Context -> Formula -> Formula -> Theorem
prop_1 gamma p q = Theorem gamma (p `Imp` (q `Imp` p))

-- |- ((p -> (q -> r)) -> ((p -> q) -> (p -> r)))
prop_2 :: Context -> Formula -> Formula -> Formula -> Theorem
prop_2 gamma p q r = Theorem gamma ((p `Imp` (q `Imp` r)) `Imp` ((p `Imp` q) `Imp` (p `Imp` r)))

-- |- ((~p -> ~q) -> (q -> p))
prop_3 :: Context -> Formula -> Formula -> Theorem
prop_3 gamma p q = Theorem gamma (((Not p) `Imp` (Not q)) `Imp` (q `Imp` p))

-- |- p & |- (p -> q) => |- q
mp :: Theorem -> Theorem -> Theorem
mp (Theorem gamma p) (Theorem gamma' (p' `Imp` q))
       = if gamma == gamma' && p == p' then Theorem gamma q else error "mp"
mp _ _ = error "mp"


-- Predicate calculus

-- |- p => |- forall v. p
gen :: Theorem -> String -> Theorem
gen (Theorem gamma p) v = Theorem gamma (Forall v p)

-- |- ((forall v. (p -> q)) -> (forall v. p) -> (forall v. q))
pred_1 :: Context -> String -> Formula -> Formula -> Theorem
pred_1 gamma v p q = Theorem gamma ((Forall v (p `Imp` q)) `Imp` ((Forall v p) `Imp` (Forall v q)))

-- |- (forall v. p -> p [t/v]) provided p admits t for v
pred_2 :: Context -> String -> Formula -> Term -> Theorem
pred_2 gamma v p t = if admitsTerm p t v then Theorem gamma ((Forall v p) `Imp` (subIn p t v)) else error "pred_2"

-- |- (p -> forall v. p) provided v is not free in p
pred_3 :: Context -> String -> Formula -> Theorem
pred_3 gamma v p = if not (freeIn v p) then Theorem gamma (p `Imp` (Forall v p)) else error "pred_3"


-- Equality

-- |- t = t
eq_1 :: Context -> Term -> Theorem
eq_1 gamma t = Theorem gamma (Pred "Eq" [t, t])

-- |- s1 = t1 ==> ... ==> sn = tn ==> f(s1,..,sn) = f(t1,..,tn)
eq_2 :: Context -> String -> [Term] -> [Term] -> Theorem
eq_2 gamma f ss ts = if length ss == length ts then
                     -- eqs = [s1 = t1, ..., sn = tn]
                     let eqs = zipWith (\s t -> (Pred "Eq" [s, t])) ss ts in
                     -- z = f(s1,..,sn) = f(t1,..,tn)
                     let z = Pred "Eq" [(Func f ss), (Func f ts)] in
                     Theorem gamma (foldr Imp z eqs)
                     else error "eq_2"

-- |- s1 = t1 ==> ... ==> sn = tn ==> P(s1,..,sn) ==> P(t1,..,tn)
eq_3 :: Context -> String -> [Term] -> [Term] -> Theorem
eq_3 gamma p ss ts = if length ss == length ts then
                     -- eqs = [s1 = t1, ..., sn = tn]
                     let eqs = zipWith (\s t -> (Pred "Eq" [s, t])) ss ts in
                     -- z = P(s1,..,sn) ==> P(t1,..,tn)
                     let z = (Pred p ss) `Imp` (Pred p ts) in
                     Theorem gamma (foldr Imp z eqs)
                     else error "eq_3"

```
````

Comment: Incidentally, for the encoding of propositions you might consider looking into "de Bruijn indices" instead of named variables -- that encoding tends to have some advantages in writing programs manipulating them.  Of course, you could still have the named-variable version, and possibly write a mini-parser which converts to de Bruijn index form.

Comment: It looks like you're going for a Hilbert-style proof system.  If that's the case, then you will probably need to specify some way of specifying a sequence of steps, in which each step is either an instantiation of an axiom or an application of modus ponens to previous steps.  (On the other hand, if you were to use a natural deduction style system instead, that would IMHO map more naturally into a Haskell type system, in that proofs have a natural tree representation.)

Comment: At this point a theorem is just a long composition of the rule and axiom functions. The next planned step is to add in the axioms of ZFC. If I can verify the correctness of this core checker, then I may move on to implement a better user interface.
I'm not sure how to implement natural deduction, but I would be very interested.

Comment: A natural deduction tree proof type could look something vaguely like `data Proof = Assumption | ImplIntro Proof | ImplElim Formula Proof Proof | ...` and then for example, a proof checker would take in the list of assumptions in the current context and the target formula, and proof checker rules could look like `proofcheck Gamma p Assumption = in p Gamma; proofcheck Gamma (Imp p q) (ImplIntro subpf) = proofcheck (p::Gamma) q subpf; proofcheck Gamma q (ImplElim p subpf1 subpf2) = proofcheck Gamma (Imp p q) subpf1 && proofcheck Gamma p subpf2;` and so on.

Comment: Oh, I missed your `mp` theorem combinator before -- so that does pretty much address my previous comment in that instead of a proof being a sequence of steps, it's a tree where internal nodes are applications of `mp` and leaves are instantiations of axioms.

Comment: In `proofcheck a b c` is `a` the context, `b` the statement to be proved given the context `a`, and `c` the proof of the statement `b` given the context `a`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you!

Comment: 1) An alternative way to implement natural deduction is to use the sequent style presentation of the rules in which the assumptions are made explicit. This is how it is done in theorem provers in the [HOL family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOL_(proof_assistant)).

Comment: 2) Depending on what you are trying to do, it may be very inconvenient to require equality rather than just $\alpha$-equivalence in rules like $\mathtt{mp}$ that compare formulas, since without that you have to reprove lemmas to rename bound variables.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I tried implementing locally nameless variables, which is a variant on the de Bruijn indices, but I'm not sure how to modify the pred_2 and pred_3 functions. I also tried implementing natural deduction, but I'm not sure how to deal with substitution in the rules (the `sub` function place holder).

Comment: @RobArthan If de Bruijn indices or locally nameless variables are used, does that turn the equality into α-equivalence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may offer better responses.

But here's a thought worth exploring: consider unit testing these functions you are nervous about. Let me walk through how I would unit test `subIn`. Here's your code:

```
{-
subIn p t v = p(t/v) = the result of replacing each free occurrence of
v in p by an occurrence of t.
-}
subIn :: Formula -> Term -> String -> Formula
subIn (Pred name terms) t v = Pred name (map (\t' -> subInTerm t' t v) terms) where
  {-
  subInTerm t' t v = t'(t/v) = the result of replacing each occurrence of
  v in t' by an occurrence of t.
  -}
  subInTerm :: Term -> Term -> String -> Term
  subInTerm (Var v') t v = if v == v' then t else Var v'
  subInTerm (Func name terms) t v = Func name (map (\t' -> subInTerm t' t v) terms)
subIn (Not p) t v = Not (subIn p t v)
subIn (Imp p q) t v = Imp (subIn p t v) (subIn q t v)
subIn (Forall v' p) t v = if v == v' then Forall v' p else Forall v' (subIn p t v)
```

Using [HUnit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit), I would make the following observations:

**Observation 1: Refactor `subInTerm`.**
OK, you've got two functions intertwined. This makes it harder to test, so I'd suggest refactoring `subInTerm` out as a separate function. (You could choose not to, but that would force us to write more tests to check `subIn (Pred P terms) t v` works as expected.)

**Observation 2.** `subInTerm (Var v') t v` has a single `if` expression and a single condition. We should have one unit test for the case when the condition is true, another unit test when the condition is false.

I would then suggest:

```
import Test.HUnit

subInMatchingVarTest1 = TestCase (assertEqual
  "subInTerm x y z = x,"
  (subInTerm (Var "x") (Var "y") "z")
  (Var "x"))

subInMatchingVarTest2 = TestCase (assertEqual
  "subInTerm x y x = y,"
  (subInTerm (Var "x") (Var "y") "x")
  (Var "y"))

{- more test cases to come -}

subInTermTests = TestList [
  TestLabel "VarMismatch" subInMatchingVarTest1,
  TestLabel "VarMatch" subInMatchingVarTest2,
  {-- more cases to come... --}
]
```

**`subInTerm` Case 2: Functions.** The other case for `subInTerm` simply replaces the arguments of a function, otherwise leaving the function untouched. The arguments of a `Func` can either be a `Var` or a `Func`, but by structural induction we only need to worry about the case when `Func`'s parameters are `Var` instances. (If a `Func` parameter is another `Func`, then by structural induction things will work out fine provided the base cases hold; i.e., if a `Func` of `Var` arguments substitutes fine.)

Thus I'd add another few unit tests (although one suffices, paranoia drives me to add a few more):

```
subInMatchingFuncTest1 = TestCase (assertEqual
  "subInTerm f (x y z) w x = f (w y z),"
  (subInTerm (Func "f" [Var "x", Var "y", Var "z"]) (Var "w") "x")
  (Func "f" [Var "w", Var "y", Var "z"]))

subInMatchingFuncTest2 = TestCase (assertEqual
  "subInTerm f (x y z) w y = f (x w z),"
  (subInTerm (Func "f" [Var "x", Var "y", Var "z"]) (Var "w") "y")
  (Func "f" [Var "x", Var "w", Var "z"]))

subInMatchingFuncTest3 = TestCase (assertEqual
  "subInTerm f (x y z) w z = f (x y w),"
  (subInTerm (Func "f" [Var "x", Var "y", Var "z"]) (Var "w") "z")
  (Func "f" [Var "x", Var "y", Var "w"]))

subInTermTests = TestList [
  TestLabel "VarMismatch" subInMatchingVarTest1,
  TestLabel "VarMatch" subInMatchingVarTest2,
  subInMatchingFuncTest1,
  subInMatchingFuncTest2,
  subInMatchingFuncTest3
]
```

**Remark 2.1.** You may want to also consider a unit test like to handle a case like `subInTerm (Func "f" [(Var "x")]) (Var "y") "f"`, just to make sure you don't end up with `Func "y" [(Var "x")]` or something similar.

When generating test cases, *think about how you can break your code* and then try to create a test case for each situation.

**Observation 3.** Of the three remaining cases for `subIn`, only `subIn (Forall v' p) t v` needs testing (the `Not` and `Imp` cases are satisfied by structural induction). There are two subcases to consider for `subIn (Forall ...) ...`:

1. `subIn (Forall (Var "x") p) t "x"`, i.e., when the bound variable `v'` in the `Forall` coincides with the variable `x` being substituted; and
2. `subIn (Forall (Var "y") p) t "x"` when the bound variable `v'` differs from the variable `x` being substituted in.

```
subInForallTest1 = TestCase (assertEqual
  "subIn (Forall x P[t]) t' x = Forall x P[t],"
  (subIn (Forall (Var "x") Pred "P" [Func "f" [(Var "x"),
                                               (Var "y"),
                                               (Var "z")]])
    (Var "w")
    "x")
  (Forall (Var "x") Pred "P" [Func "f" [(Var "x"), (Var "y"), (Var "z")]]))

subInForallTest2 = TestCase (assertEqual
  "subIn (Forall x P[t]) t' y = Forall x P[subIn t t' y],"
  (subIn (Forall (Var "x") Pred "P" [Func "f" [(Var "x"),
                                               (Var "y"),
                                               (Var "z")]])
    (Var "w")
    "y")
  (Forall (Var "x") Pred "P" [Func "f" [(Var "x"), (Var "w"), (Var "z")]]))

subInForallTest3 = TestCase (assertEqual 
  "subIn (Forall x P[t]) t' z = Forall x P[subIn t t' z]," 
  (subIn (Forall (Var "x") Pred "P" [Func "f" [(Var "x"),
                                               (Var "y"),
                                               (Var "z")]])
    (Var "w")
    "z")
  (Forall (Var "x") Pred "P" [Func "f" [(Var "x"), (Var "y"), (Var "w")]]))

{- other tests placed here -}

subInTests = TestList [subInForallTest1,
  subInForallTest2,
  subInForallTest3]
```

Now, given that we tested the `subInTerm` function, the `subIn (Pred ...)` case would be handled. But I encourage a little caution, and you may want to add some tests to handle this case (handle special cases like `subIn (Pred (Func "f" [])) ...` should be invariant, and also "generic" cases which would cover a huge class of situations like `subIn (Pred "P" [(Var "x")]) (Var "w") "x"` and `subIn (Pred "P" [(Var "y")]) (Var "w") "x"`).

**Concluding remarks.** The strategy should be to test each possible "flow", and partition the "input space" into equivalence classes, then test each equivalence class with some finite number of representative cases. We can cut down on the number of tests by using structural induction (in Haskell, at least). But this is the generic strategy to test the code.

Testing doesn't prove the absence of bugs, however. Whenever you encounter a bug, you should add a unit test which reflects the bug you've encountered. Run unit tests before pushing commits (I'm assuming you're using git, right?), or set up Jenkins or another "continuous integration" tool to run tests when a commit has been pushed (and email out warnings when the tests have failed).

If you **really** want greater confidence, consider using [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck), which would automatically generate test cases to see if specified properties hold. Again, this doesn't prove the absence of bugs, but it increases the plausibility that there are no serious bugs.